# Zend Framework issue with Routes in Searchform when using Paging

Tags: zend-framework

I am sure this is only a small issue, but I am trying now since 2 days to find a solution. I have a Action Helper, which creates me a Search Form which is displayed in the Layout File. I also created some Routes. Everything works fine, besides when I try to use paging aswell for the Search Result Page. My Sourcecode so far:

```
// ===== bootstrap.php =====
$searchRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
 'search.html/page(\d*)', 
    array(                                          
      'controller' => 'search',
      'action'  => 'search',
      'page'    => 1
          ),
    array(
      1 => 'page'           
        ),
    'search.html/page%d'                                                      
);

$router->addRoute('simpleSearch',$searchRoute);

// ==== Search Form =====
->setAction($this->getView()->url(array('page' => 1), 'simpleSearch'))
```

I keep getting the Error Message:
***Cannot assemble. Too few arguments?*** I know that this is connected with setting up the Routes wrongly, I think about Parameters, but I really can not see, where my Error could be. Can any of you guys see the mistake?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Is this exactly the code you're using or did you trim some stuff out for the question? The error suggests the page parameter is not being passed to the URL helper (which it is in your example).

Comment: Yes, its the code I am using. I have used the following tutorial http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/a-form-in-your-layout/ besides that my form is a simple Search Form. I am than calling up my SearchController and in there the paging gets set up.